# Problems with user-friendly URLs on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to use a **htaccess** file on my localhost in order to create user-friendly URLs. But I've not gotten a happy ending so far: I can't make it work properly. Here are the details:

I have the Apache running on **Windows**. My localhost is here: C:\AppServ\www\, so I accede to my local site ("university") through the next path with the browser: localhost/university

I have this url:

**localhost/university/university.php?filter=private**

And I want to be read simply like this:

**localhost/university/university/private**

So, I write the next code into my htaccess file (the file is into this folder C:\AppServ\www\university)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^university/private$ university.php?filter=private
```

That doesn't work. That opens university.php without any style. (In fact, when I have no htaccess file, if I try to accede to localhost/university/university/private, I have no 404 error; I have the same university.php without any style instead.)

But I have success when I write the next rule:

```
RewriteRule ^private$ university/university.php?filter=private
```

This work fine to localhost/university/private but not to localhost/university/university/private

I have no clue about where is the problem. Do you have one?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That opens university.php without any style.

This is probably because you have relative URI's to access your style sheets, and the extra path node (`/private`) is making the browser think the styles are in the private folder, which doesn't exist. Try adding a relative URI base to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/university/" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That works fine. But I still have no clue about this: "In fact, when I have no htaccess file, if I try to accede to localhost/university/university/private, I have no 404 error; I have the same university.php without any style instead"

Comment: @Angel You probably need to turn multiviews off. Add this to your htaccess file: `Options -Multiviews`

Comment: Thank you again! This work fine! So Options -Multiviews was the solution. The only problem now is how to work together <base href="/university/" /> with the history.pushState which had been working fine refreshing the hash till now . When the browser refreshes the url with history.pushState, now it ignores "university/private/ and adds the hash to the base of the <base href="/university/"/>. Any solution avoiding absolute URLs?

Comment: @Angel instead of the `<base />` tag, you could just change all of your script URL's to be absolute paths (starts with a `/`). So you'd add a `/university/` in front of all the script URLs.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine changing to absolute paths. For the moment, I'll use <base> and then, when the site be ready to be online, I'll have to change to absolute path.